# Object Property is undefined/doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I ran into problem where the customer email input will matched with the mySQL database and later I would compare the passwords form the database, however, it is not working. I cant find a solution

Running a query returns 1 matching object, outputs the values, however, object.property comes back undefined, thus, I am assuming the object has not properties whatsoever. I need to be able to access the object keys as needed.

```
`router.post('/login', async function (req, res) {
    const userData = req.body;
    const enteredEmail = userData.email;
    const enteredPassword = userData.password;

    const [existingUser] = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?`, [enteredEmail,]);
    console.log(Object.keys(existingUser).length);
    console.log(typeof existingUser);
    console.log(existingUser);
    const check = existingUser.hasOwnProperty('email');
    console.log(check);
    console.log(existingUser.email);

I get 

1
object
[
  {
    email: 'run@gmail.com',
    password: '$2a$10$yK8Pvrc2BzIXKez2X5XOYuS1IInyAs/uugOSke4HWNWPVzSzfavta'
  }
]
false
undefined
`
```

Comment: `existingUser` is actually an array of results from the query. `existingUser[0].email`. Of course if there are more results, you're probably looking to put it inside a loop :)

Comment: Yep, I will restrict double registration under the same email, this way, it will always return only one user. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects, you have to access those elements by their index (0 if only one element in array)

This code will always return false

```
const check = existingUser.hasOwnProperty('email');
```

and this code will always be undefined

```
console.log(existingUser.email);
```

so your code should look like this

```
    const userData = req.body;
    const enteredEmail = userData.email;
    const enteredPassword = userData.password;

    const [existingUser] = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?`, [enteredEmail,]);
    console.log(Object.keys(existingUser).length);
    console.log(typeof existingUser);
    console.log(existingUser);
    const check = existingUser[0].hasOwnProperty('email');//index 0
    console.log(check);
    console.log(existingUser[0].email);//access email key of the 1st element in your array
```

Output

```
1
"object"
[
  {
    email: 'run@gmail.com',
    password: '$2a$10$yK8Pvrc2BzIXKez2X5XOYuS1IInyAs/uugOSke4HWNWPVzSzfavta'
  }
]
true
"run@gmail.com"
```

Comment: It was much easier than I thought after you showed the way. Awesome, thanks so much.

Comment: To recap: the reason the properties of an object were not available, because my object was inside an array, thus, the access request needs to be adjusted accordingly. Right?

Comment: that is correct